# High-performance 8-byte-hex to float value conversion?

Tags: c#, performance, type-conversion

I need to convert a lot of values stored as 8-character hex strings into float values within a C# program. Performance is critical as the code will be called up to a 50,000 times a second.

As for functionality, the Python code:

```
f = struct.unpack('<f', bytes.fromhex(strng))[0]
```

does what I need. I have tried the "boring" version:

```
byte[] raw = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
Array.Reverse(raw);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(raw, 0);
```

but this is dreadfully slow. I have tried to optimise it using the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/447938/High-performance-Csharp-byte-array-to-hex-string-t)
and which uses table lookup and c# pointers, and calling it this way:

```
byte[] raw = FastHex.FromHexString(hex);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(raw, 0);
```

which is great for the hext-to-byte[] conversion, but still involves non-local byte[] array creation  and destruction. I wonder whether I can go straight from the byte[] to the "float" value at the end of the FromHexString() code. That is, I would like to be able to do:

```
fixed (float* floatptr = (float*)result)
    return *floatptr;
```

where result is the byte[4] containing the result, but C# doesn't like that... is there a better way?

Comment: So your hex strings are in MSB-to-LSB order?

Comment: They're coming from an external app running on an Intel PC.Python's "<f" operator is a little-endian conversion, which is what I expect, but when I initially coded the int.Parse version, I found the float values coming out were wrong, and were corrected by the array reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do the trick:

```
float f = (float)System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(
    BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0));
```

Comment: - as far as converting from byte-array to float, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // This works for a two byte string, possibly more ;-)
        string hex = "FF";
        //
        float f = (float) Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
        //
        // f is now 255, yahoo!
```